# How can you display a user's username and password in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I am a beginner programmer who has completed a Ruby on Rails bootcamp, but I have very little experience with PHP. I currently am developing an company training course using Moodle, and one of the requirements of the site is that each user will have their username and password displayed for them on a certain page in the course so that they can access a course-related App on their mobile devices. I have looked through the MoodleDocs and found nothing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is **never** recommended to store nor display user literal credentials in any place of your application. You should search for another way, like generating random keys with expiration time. Nevertheless, if your user has its username and password to access your application, it's supposed to already *know* its credentials and therefore having no need to show it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

No is the simple answer, the password is stored in the db using a md5 or sha1 hash, so its pretty much impossible to extract the password.

If you need to connect to another app, then use one of the external authentication methods.

If the database is on the same server then external database authentication is probably the easiest to set up

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/External_database_authentication

Answer (score 1):

You can show the users username using the global variable $USER

```
$USER->username;
```

But as others suggested is impossible to show password in clean text to the user.

Maybe [Moodle Web services](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) can help you achieve what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can't access password as it is encrypted with `md5` and `sha1`. 
But, from what I understood from your question is that you want to authenticate user through your app on `moodle`. For this, you can take use `moodle web services` and `moodle's auth plugins`.

If you want to display the current user's `username`, you can do as follows:

```
global $USER;
echo $USER->username;
```